# Regex expression to match equal or greater than 0,5 or 0.5, by increments of .5

Tags: regex

I am trying enhance the given answer on another post:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.[05])?$
```

Breakup:

```
^        # Start of input
[1-9]    # match digit 1 to 9
\d*      # match 0 or more of any digits
(?:      # start of non-capturing group
\.       # match a decimal
[05]     # followed by digit 0 or 5
)?       # end non-capturing group. (? makes this group optional)
$        # End of input
```

Only this time the regex needs to accept 0,5 or 0.5 and increments of 0,5 or 0.5

The number zero is the only one that can't be matched.

Already tried:

```
(?!0).{1}|^[1-9]\d*(?:(,|\.)[05])?$
```

and

```
[^0]|^[1-9]\d*(?:(,|\.)[05])?$
```

Can you help please?

Comment: change `1-9` to `0-9`...?

Comment: What are sample inputs?

Comment: Try `^[0-9]\d*(?:[,.][05])?$`

Comment: Must accept 0,5 or 0.5 Number 0 is not allowed. Commas or point should be allowed as decimal separator. Increments by 0.5 (or 0,5) are matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!0$)\d+(?:[,.][05])?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ6dY5/7)

This will match your required numbers and will exclude a `0`-only number thanks to the look-ahead at the beginning.

Main changes:

- `\d+` - replaced `[1-9]\d*` to allow a `0` as the integer part
- `[,.]` - replace `\.` to allow a comma as a decimal separator.
- The lookahead adds a `0`-number exception.

The lookahead can be enhanced to disallow `0.000`-like input:

```
^(?!0+(?:[,.]0+)?$)\d+(?:[,.][05])?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ6dY5/6).

Comment: So if I understood correctly: ^(?!0$) ignore number (single) zero

Comment: [0-9]\d* what does this mean?

Comment: (?:[,.][05])?$  optional but I think that states accept commas and point followed by zero or five

Comment: Yes, the lookahead will add an exception to the whole input. `(?!0$)` will disallow `0`, or `(?!0+$)` will disallow `0000`. I have updated the regex, I guess the integer part must be at least 1 digit, right? Please check the [latest demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJ6dY5/6).

Comment: I see it works for you, great. The lookahead is a negative one, that is why the decimal point/comma and 0 or 5 cannot be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:5|[1-9]\d*[05])(?:[,.][05])?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mV3wC2/3)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
^(?!0*$)0?\d*([,.]5)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/j076a78sB9).

This uses `^\d*([,.]5)?$` to match what you want, and uses `^(?!0*([,.]0*)?$)` to exclude zero in all its forms, ie it won.t match 0, 000 etc